# How to prevent modal scrolling when I scroll div inside it on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal open and inside it I create a div with overflow:auto. When I'm on desktop it works fine but on mobile when I scroll the content of that div modal also scroll. How can I prevent modal scroll when I scroll the div??

I use a plugin scrollbar **perfectscrollBar.js**.

in my modal body I have this div

```
<div class="list"><ul></ul></div>
```

and from javascript I add `<li></li>` so it become:

```
<div class="list">
 <ul>
  <li>Jhon</li>
  <li>Mark</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The div with class **list** has this css:

```
.list {
  height: 70px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

so when I populate the div it will be scrollable. 
The custom scrollbar **perfecscrollBar.js** is simple implemented from jquery:

```
$(".list").perfectScrollbar();
```

Comment: Some of your relevant code could possibly help us to get a solution for your situation. Please add code, thank you.

Comment: To prevent scrolling, you need to define some height equal to or smaller than the viewport height, and add `overflow: hidden;` to the scrolling element.  The question is, which element do you add that on?  Try to figure out which element is scrolling, and then add `height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;` (or some other height value)

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah thanks now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem thanks to the answer on the follow comment by @RaphaelRafatpanah

[Correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307295/how-to-prevent-modal-scrolling-when-i-scroll-div-inside-it-on-mobile?noredirect=1#comment75619882_44307295)